# Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect EMFILE

Tags: node.js, redis

So I created, an realtime application using socket.io, redis and node.js.

The problem is that with 30 users, I'm already reaching the number of connections of the server ( I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

And I think it has something to do about the way I connect to redis.

So on one page, I have at most 12 channels to subscribe to. On two socket.io connections, one has 6 channels and the other has the other 6 channels.

Before showing my node js code, what I do, is for each channel, I create a new redis client, so let's say that I have an *insert* and *update* channel, on the node.js code, so my code wiil be:

```
var data = io.of('/data');
data.on('connection', function(client) {
    var insert = redis.createClient();
    var update = redis.createClient();

    insert.subscribe('insert');

    insert.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        client.emit('data_insert', message);
    });

    update.subscribe('update');
    update.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        client.emit('data_update', message);
    });
});
```

I believe that this is the problem, and that why, with 30 users I'm exceeding the limit of connections of the server, since 30 * 12 + 2 * 30 = 420, plus a few others for everything else, and it's easy to reach 1024.

So how can I optimize the code, to reduce the number of connections per client to one or two the max?

Does it help, to have the *var insert = redis.createClient();* outside the *data.on('connection')*??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be creating one (or more) redis connections per client - just keep using the same global one.  Further, there's really no reason to create a client for each channel you want to subscribe to.  Just use the `channel` argument to figure out which thing to do with the data (in this case, you're doing the same thing on each channel, so even less point in having separate ones).

```
var data = io.of('/data');
var redis = redis.createClient();
redis.subscribe('insert');
redis.subscribe('update');
data.on('connection', function(client) {
    redis.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        if(channel == 'insert')
            client.emit('data_insert', message);
        else if(channel == 'update')
            client.emit('data_update', message);
    });
});
```

There are probably better ways to do this, but this is a fairly direct translation of your code into something that uses only one redis connection.

Note that redis subcribers can *only* subscribe - you will need a second client to publish or do any other redis operations.

Comment: Sorry, actually I'm trying to do separate things, it was an error, could you give me a code example, because every time I try to use the same redis client, I only get the first subscription, not the second..

Comment: yep, I actually managed to solved it yesterday, doing something like that, for me the only change is that I need to have the subscribe inside the data.on('connection') due to a variable being passed, that select's the correct channel, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

just for your information (I lost this evening with that)

This does not work (it defaults connecting to localhost:6379 whatever you put in the url):

```
const redisURL = "redis://foo.bar.org:6379"
redis.createClient( redisURL )
```

but this DOES WORK (it tries to connect too foo.bar.org)

```
redis.createClient( {url: redisURL} )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use socket.io's [namespace](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/). Within each namespace you can also define rooms but namespace should be enough for your needs.

Comment: actually, I'm already using socket.io's namespace, as you can see in the example I posted..